# How to make Symfony translation not to take values and translate labels only?

Tags: symfony, translation

Sonata Amin bundle
Translation works correctly (in thw whole) - takes translations from messages.ru.yaml. 
BUT
It tries to translate not only labels, but also data values loaded from DB.
For example, I have bouquets and their category.
Bouquet categiries kept in DB table and when I edit bouquet, I can choose category in select/option built by Sonata Admin from table data.
And translator tries to translate all values of bouquet categoty (in select/options) taken from DB
**Not labels - VALUES!**
In the console
php bin/console debug:translation ru --only-missing
I cant see them in list
But I can see  them in Missing Messages  in Sonata Admin page (/_profiler/956513?panel=translation)
**How to make translation not to take theese values and translate labels only?**
ru  messages    1   no description (id: 1)  no description (id: 1)
ru  messages    1   no description (id: 2)  no description (id: 2)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved by param
'choice_translation_domain' => false,

```html
            ->add('category', ModelType::class, [
                'choice_translation_domain' => false,
                'class' => FlowerCategory::class
            ])
```